# Which version of Signal Desktop is legit?

Tags: apt, security, signal

I saw both of these in the apt sources.  Since this is a secure communications app, what is the correct source to use for Ubuntu?  Searching for Signal, I see:

[image]

[image]

And lower:

[image]

With these details:

[image]

[image]

Before thinking this is an unnecessary abundance of caution, you can see there is an effort to create frauds out there:

- Authoritative: https://github.com/signalapp
- vs. presumably fake/nefarious: https://github.com/whispersystems

Please don't mark this as a duplicate unless you can guarantee these two applications are identical except for being a snap versus a source.  If you can demonstrate they're identical, then submit that as an answer.  This is a question not because the asker doesn't know what a snap is, but in order to disambiguate and provide authority for this security conscious application.

Comment: I understand how snaps work, but I'd like clarification on which is authoritative for this particular application.  As you can see, there are active attempts to create misleading information here.  Would be great to point to clarity.